# Query creates load on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I have made a query

```
Select         
-- Generate the row number        
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by MenuOrder) as 'rownum',        
-- get the minimum data from query        
(Select top 1 ROW_NUMBER()over(order by MenuOrder)          
from SitePage where ActiveFlag='true' AND SiteId=1083 and LanguageId=159 AND ChildOf=0 order by MenuOrder asc) as 'min',        
-- get the maximum data from query        
(Select top 1 ROW_NUMBER()over(order by MenuOrder)  from SitePage where ActiveFlag='true' and LanguageId=159 AND SiteId=1083 AND ChildOf=0         
order by MenuOrder desc) as 'max',        
-- get rest of all details        
*,(case when exists(select *from SitePage where ChildOf = AP.SitePageId and ActiveFlag =1  ) then 'Y' else 'N' end) as [Type]  from SitePage AP 
where ActiveFlag=1 AND SiteId=1083 AND ChildOf=0 and LanguageId=159 order by MenuOrder
```

after that when I saw the  query performance  it  takes so much time to execute which creates load on sql server causing unexpected server down

**here is total_elapsed_time_in_Seconds: 61480**

How can I reduce the total_elapsed_time_in_Seconds

Comment: You should review execution plan. Do you have any indexes on these tables? And I'm not sure if 'min' subquery can return something different from 1. Could you clarify role of 'min' and 'max' subqueries? Why not top 1, why `MenuOrder` does not fit your needs. Review `ActiveFlag` field usage: is it numeric/tinying or varchar?

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your query by refactoring it, for instance you are executing a full query to get the minimum `ROW_NUMBER()`, this will always be 1. Similarly there is no need for a separate subquery to get the maximum, since the filters are exactly the same you can just use `COUNT(*) OVER()` in the main query.

The next thing you should do is not use `SELECT *` and only return the columns you need, even if this is all of them it [still good practise to state all the columns](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

```
SELECT  RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ap.MenuOrder),
        [Min] = 1,
        [Max] = COUNT(*) OVER(),
        [Type] = ISNULL(t.[Type], 'N'),
        ap.Column1,
        ap.Column2,
        ap.Column3
FROM    SitePage AS ap 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 'Y'
            FROM    SitePage AS ap2
            WHERE   ap2.ChildOf = ap.SitePageID
            AND     ap2.ActiveFlag = 1
        ) AS t ([Type])
WHERE   ap.ActiveFlag = 1 
AND     ap.SiteId = 1083 
AND     ap.ChildOf = 0 
AND     ap.LanguageId = 159 
ORDER BY ap.MenuOrder;
```

This should already improve performance, but it is likely that indexes will further improve this. It is pretty hard to know what the best index will be without knowing your data, but a good place to start would be to run with "Show Actual Execution Plan" enabled in SSMS, then this will suggest indexes for you. This is by no means an exact science, but it should get you started in the right direction.